# Error 3221225477: El programa se rompe

Tags: c++, array

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<limits>
#include<algorithm>
#define hrmax1 40
#define hrmax2 80
using namespace std;

void check()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

int main()
{
    int limemp, noemp = 1, horas, hrextra;
    double extra, ingr, jnor, total;
    string opc = "si";
    string *name[noemp];
    string *surname[noemp];
    char ace = 130, aca = 160, aco = 162, acu = 163, acn = 164, interr = 168;
    do {
        cout << "Introduzca la cantidad de empleados a registrar (use 0 para salir): ";
        while (!(cin >> limemp) || limemp < 0)
        {
            cout << "Intente de nuevo: ";
            check();
        }
        if (limemp == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        cout << "Introduzca el salario por hora: ";
        while (!(cin >> ingr) || limemp < 0)
        {
            cout << "Intente de nuevo: ";
            check();
        }
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
        for (noemp = 1; noemp <= limemp; noemp++)
        {
            name[noemp] = new string;
            surname[noemp] = new string;
            cout << "==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #" << noemp << ": ENTRADA==" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Introduzca el/los nombre(s) del empleado #" << noemp << ": ";
            getline( cin, *name[noemp] );
            cout << "Introduzca los apellidos del empleado #" << noemp << ": ";
            getline( cin, *surname[noemp] );
            cout << "Cantidad de horas [a la semana] en las que labora " << *name[noemp] << " " <<*surname[noemp] << ": ";
            while (!(cin >> horas))
            {
                cout << "Intente de nuevo: ";
                check();
            }
            system("cls");
            cout << "==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #" << noemp << ": SALIDA==" << endl << endl;
            jnor = ingr * horas;
            {
                if (noemp >= 1 || noemp <= 9)
                cout << "ID del empleado: #00" << noemp;
                else if (noemp >= 10 || noemp <= 99)
                cout << "ID del empleado: #0" << noemp;
                else if (noemp >= 100)
                cout << "ID del empleado: #" << noemp;
            }
            cout << endl << "Nombre del empleado: " << *surname[noemp] << ", " << *name[noemp] << endl;
            cout << "Horas laboradas: " << horas << endl;
            cout << "Salario por hora: $" << ingr << endl;
            cout << "Total a pagar - Jornada normal: $" << jnor << endl;
            if (horas > hrmax1 && horas < hrmax2)
            {
                hrextra = horas - hrmax1;
                extra = 2.73 * hrextra;
                total = jnor + extra;
                cout << "Horas extra: " << hrextra << endl;
                cout << "Excedente a pagar: $" << extra << endl;
                cout << "Total a pagar - J. normal ($" << jnor << ") + Horas extra ($" << extra << "): $" << total << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            horas = 0;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        cout << endl << interr << "Quieres reiniciar el programa? (Si/No) -> ";
    cond: //Etiqueta para saber si se reinicia el programa o si se cierra.
        cin >> opc; //Se lee la opción.
        transform(opc.begin(), opc.end(), opc.begin(), ::tolower); //Se convierte la entrada en minúsculas, haciendo que nuestra entrada sea insensible.
        if (opc == "si" || opc == "s") //Condiciones a evaluar. Si la entrada es "Si":
        {
            horas = 0;
            ingr = 0;
            system("cls");             //Se limpia la consola.
            continue;                  //Y se continúa el bucle.
        }
        if (opc == "no" || opc == "n") //Si la entrada es "No":
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Cerrando...\n";
            return 0;                  //Sólo se "finaliza la ejecución de una función y devuelve el control a la función de llamada" -Microsoft.
        }
        else                           //Si la entrada que se ha dado no coincide con las de arriba:
        {
            while (!((opc == "si" || opc == "s") || (opc == "no" || opc == "n")))   //Se hace otro bucle con el cuál se evitará el cierre o reinicio del programa.
            {
                cout << "Intenta de nuevo: ";
                cin.clear();                                                        //Se limpia la entrada errónea
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');                //y la descartamos.
                goto cond;                                                          //Por último hacemos referencia a nuestra etiqueta.
            }
        }
    } while (opc == "si" || opc == "s");        
    return 0;
}
```

El problema es el siguiente: **el programa se comienza a romper si el empleado es el número 5**.
Esto significa que, si al inicio establecemos que se van a registrar 5 o más empleados, el programa se romperá y dejará de funcionar hasta el sexto empleado.

Es decir:

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #4: ENTRADA==

Introduzca el/los nombre(s) del empleado #4: Elliot
Introduzca los apellidos del empleado #4: Stiko IV
Cantidad de horas [a la semana] en las que labora Elliot Stiko IV: 45
```

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #4: SALIDA==

ID del empleado: #004
Nombre del empleado: Stiko IV, Elliot
Horas laboradas: 45
Salario por hora: $500
Total a pagar - Jornada normal: $22500
Horas extra: 5
Excedente a pagar: $13.65
Total a pagar - J. normal ($22500) + Horas extra ($13.65): $22513.7
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
/*Aquí el programa se pausa para revisar resultados; al presionar una tecla la consola se limpia*/
```

Así se muestra desde el primer empleado hasta el cuarto empleado, al menos al utilizar la misma cantidad de horas laboradas (es decir, 45).

Aquí se pone feo:

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #5: ENTRADA==

Introduzca el/los nombre(s) del empleado #5: Elliot
Introduzca los apellidos del empleado #5: Stiko V
Cantidad de horas [a la semana] en las que labora Elliot Stiko V: 45
/*Nótese que aún estoy utilizando el mismo valor que en la entrada del empleado anterior.*/
```

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #5: SALIDA==

ID del empleado: #005
Nombre del empleado: Stiko V, Elliot
Horas laboradas: 45
Salario por hora: $5.77579e-317                /*Aquí empieza a dejar valores gigantescos, a pesar de que el salario por hora es de $500, entonces $500 * 45hrs = $22513.7*/
Total a pagar - Jornada normal: $2.5991e-315   /*El mismo comportamiento se ve aquí*/
Horas extra: 5
Excedente a pagar: $13.65                      /*Aquí también*/
Total a pagar - J. normal ($2.5991e-315) + Horas extra ($13.65): $13.65 /*Y en estas dos salidas: J. normal y hrs. extra.*/
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #6: ENTRADA==

Introduzca el/los nombre(s) del empleado #6: Elliot
Introduzca los apellidos del empleado #6: Stiko VI
Cantidad de horas [a la semana] en las que labora Elliot Stiko VI: 45
/*Aquí también utilizo las 45hrs*/
```

Y el programa se rinde aquí.

```
==DATOS DEL EMPLEADO #6: SALIDA==

ID del empleado: #006
Nombre del empleado: Stiko VI, /*No escribió el nombre o el resto de la salida.*/
--------------------------------
Process exited after 475.8 seconds with return value 3221225477
```

¿Hay alguna explicación detrás de esto?

Comment: Aparte de lo que puse, tienes la variable `noemp` **sin inicializar**. Osea, son **varios** errores. Intenta eliminar algunos.

Comment: Lo que dejaste [en tu última edición] solucionó el problema, pero a pesar de que se podía compilar, al ejecutarlo el _getline_ se saltaba. Esta vez utilicé el `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');` antes y después del bucle for y el programa funciona de maravilla. ¡Te lo agradezco mucho! :D

Comment: Por cierto, borraste tu respuesta :(

Comment: Acabo de utilizar `vector`, pero ahora devuelve otro valor de error: 3221225725. No puedo avanzar del nombre.

Answer (score 2):

El número 3221225477 en hexadecimal es C0000005‬, que se corresponde con una [violación de acceso](https://wiki-tech.net/es/errors/b/0x/c0000005%20access%20violation).

---

La violación de acceso suele suceder cuando accedes a memoria que no pertenece a tu proceso. Muy probablemente se de cuando accedes a la formación `name` en una posición inexistente.

Esto seguramente pasa porque creas memoria para `name` usando una variable no inicializada:

```
int limemp, noemp, horas = 0, hrextra = 0;
//          ^^^^^ <--- noemp NO TIENE VALOR ESTABLECIDO
double extra = 0;
string *name = new string[noemp]; // ¿De qué tamaño es name?
```

La variable no inicializada tendrá un valor residual que puede ser desde cero a *vete-tú-a-saber-cuánto*, si el valor aleatorrio de `noemp` es menor al valor que lees sobre `limemp`, entonces tu acceso fallará en el bucle:

```
for (noemp = 1; noemp <= limemp; noemp++)
{
    cout << "Introduzca el nombre del empleado #" << noemp << ": ";
    // Fallo si limemp es menor que el valor que tenía noemp
    //           vvvvvvvvvvv
    getline(cin, name[noemp]);
    // Fallo si limemp es menor que el valor que tenía noemp
    //                                                vvvvvvvvvvv
    cout << "Cantidad de horas en las que labora " << name[noemp] << ": ";
```

Eso sin tener en cuenta que las formaciones en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) se indexan desde cero, es decir: van de 0 a tamaño-1, por lo que tu bucle está mal. De no hacerlo así, accederás a la posición posterior a la última reservada. Posiblemente querías hacer esto:

```
int limemp, horas = 0, hrextra = 0;
double extra = 0;
string name[TAMAÑO]; // Usa el tamaño que creas conveniente.

// ...

for (int noemp = 0; noemp != limemp; ++noemp) // De 0 a limemp-1
{
    // ...
```

Comment: No veo en el código que muestras que el tamaño de `name` esté definido por el usuario.

Comment: O sea, lo que se hace es que se crea otra variable `name`, según el valor de `noemp` en el bucle _for_.

Comment: Ya vi mi error. A lo que me refería era que `noemp` depende un poco de `limemp`, que es definido por el usuario. En el bucle for, una vez que `noemp` sea menor o igual a `limemp` el bucle termina y se pregunta si se quiere repetir el programa.

Comment: Igualmente actualicé la publicación con el código hasta donde lo dejé.

Comment: Has modificado la publicación y sigues teniendo exáctamente el mismo error que antes (`noemp` puede ser menor que el valor que el usuario defina) pero además has añadido un error adicional: el uso de Formaciones de Tamaño Variable lee [estos hilos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+vla) para saber más del tema.